# Is accessing IOptions<T> cause performance issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, appsettings

I have a high usage action inside my asp.net core app and it used IOptions. my question is should i use IOptionsMonitor or something else instead of IOptions to get better performance?

my settings rarely changed and there's no problem to restart app (to get updated value)

Comment: IOptions<> doesn't update when settings change and there's only one-per-name-per-type  (if you only ever use the default it's essentially singleton). You're unlikely to have performance implications with either variant as it's such small potatoes compared to everything else going on behind the scenes (and if any of them were to actually have impact I'd suspect it'd be mobitor/Snapshot). Short answer no, longer answer don't worry about it until/if it shows up in profiling

Comment: As with all questions about performance. Start by measuring, either with a profiler, or just a stopwatch.